# How to build connection string in C# to remote SQL Server using intermediate Jump server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, vpn, remote-access

In Visual Studio, I am trying to build a connection to a remote SQL Server. To access this server manually:

- I need to connect to the VPN
- then RDP to Jump server
- then RDP to SSMS on the existing server
- Open SSMS & perform operation.

How can I achieve this using VS and C#?

**Note**: without Jump, remote connection to other SQL Servers via VPN is possible, but this server needs me to connect intermediate Jump server 1st. Port, Firewall settings are proper.

Your answers will be really helpful & appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need to have direct access to the server to make a connection.

Comment: `then RDP to Jump server` no you don't need that. Or SSMS. SSMS is a client application just like any other. If you have a VPN you can connect to the database server or ask the network administrator to configure this for you. If you aren't allowed to do that, then maybe you shouldn't be trying to connect to that server at all. Perhaps your application should be hosted on that server. Or perhaps you should create an HTTP API to perform the data access.

Comment: @Panagiotis using firewalls, you can configure a lot. As I understand, the SQL server only allows traffic in through the "jump server", the latter thereby being a gateway into the application server. Traffic originating from other hosts (such as the VPN terminator) isn't accepted.

Comment: You need to contact the servers team to give you a way to connect to the SQL from your machine, if not possible, your only way is to take a backup and restore it locally, then work on your app using that backup, and when you finish, update the actual database using that backup.

Comment: _this server needs me to connect intermediate Jump server..._ No, the team that manages this machine and all the networking separating you from it require that. Talk to those people.

Comment: Neither SQL Server itself nor SSMS have any kind of logic for proxying or remoting connections, nor do the client-side drivers support that, so you cannot embed logic for this in a connection string. You would need to run your application on a machine that has access, no matter where that machine is.